# Is there a way to return an empty string for a null object in Groovy when setting values in a constructor?

Tags: groovy

I know Groovy has the null check operator `?`, where you can do something like: `params.name?` which will check if it's null, and return null. Is there a way to return the empty string instead of a null? Something like:

```
params.name? "" : params.name
```

When you're creating a new object and you're passing in a value for the class variables, like:

```
Foo myObj = new Foo(name : params.name? "" : params.name)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [named parameters with default values in groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001965/named-parameters-with-default-values-in-groovy)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you have the order wrong here.  `x ? y : x` would return x, if x *is* null (falsey).  Turn that code around: `params.name ? params.name : ""` or even shorter: `params.name ?: ""`

Also `?` is no operator in groovy.  Both the `?` and `:` form the [Ternary Operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_ternary_operator) or the shorter version `?:` called the [Elvis Operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_elvis_operator)